# use a.all() or a.any() error while trying to use gensim word2vec

Tags: python-2.7, gensim, word2vec

I've been trying to run an example of how t use word2vec from the gensim library of python but I keep getting this error

```
    ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

This is my code, it's just a simple example :

```
    from gensim.models import Word2Vec
    sentences = [['first', 'sentence'], ['second', 'sentence']]
    # train word2vec on the two sentences
    model = Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1)
```

Note: I've made sure that gensim is installed with all its dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same exact problem too, what i did was installing python-dev package then re-installing gensim, somehow that worked, i'm on ubuntu so this is what i did :

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
sudo pip uninstall gensim
sudo pip install gensim
```

when i run this :

```
model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(sentences=listSentence,min_count=2,window=3,size=20,workers=1)
print model['Brasil']
```

it worked and i got the result vector :

```
[-0.01635483  0.02224622 -0.01865266  0.02168317 -0.01231722 -0.0207897
 -0.0014509   0.00264822 -0.01889374 -0.02109174 -0.00244757  0.00024959
 -0.00898884 -0.01826199 -0.01361686 -0.01770178 -0.02431025 -0.01903439
 -0.00775641  0.02353667]
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, I sort of figured it out too. The problem is from the python-dev installation.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this problem as well. For me the error apparently had another background:

Usually, I collect text-data into numpy-arrays of `dtype=np.str`.
When I loaded the numpy-text-array into the gensim-model, I received the error you describe. Actually, storing the array in a normal python-`list` instead did the trick..

Maybe this helps out somebody else running into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

if all the above answer dont work, you can try to save txt from you numpy list,and then like this .

```
np.savetxt('train_data.txt', np_api, delimiter=" ", fmt="%s")
sentences = word2vec.LineSentence('train_data.txt')
```

the txt's fmt must like this

```
this is the sentence a
this is the sentence b
```

if the txt have other word like "["or "]" or "'",you may have this answer,you wont like that

```
"'FindWindowA'": <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7f1f74251e80>,
"'FindWindowA']": <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7f1f74232978>,
"'FindWindowExA'": <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7f1f741e83c8>,
```